# entity_id/entity_type terminology/pattern?

Tags: mysql, database, schema, relational-database

Is there a name or a pattern for a schema like this:

```
movies
======
id

series
======
id


assets
======
entity_type  (i.e. 'movies' or 'series')
entity_id    (the id of either the movie or series record)
...
```

I'm not asking if it's a good or bad idea - just if it has a name and/or associated pattern.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is known as polymorphic associations.